# Prohibited characters for database entry?

Tags: mysql, json, innodb

i play on a FiveM server and we use an in-game MDT to list and track warrants. for some reason, when this is entered to add an entry, it breaks the whole system from being accessed, does anyone know if there are prohibited characters used?

"Suspect":"MISHA","Description":"Black sports vehicle with plate: MISHA. Reckless driving on the FWY and through the city. Refuses to show ID and says "Do you know who my husband is officer?" then drives off.","OfficerC":"Disobeying a Peace Officer | Reckless Driving | Failure to Obey Traffic Controlled Devices (x4) | Speeding (55MPH+) (C. Larsen | A-782)", "Date":"Thu Jul 25 12:56:56 2019"}

its being entered into this field
[image]

utf8_general_ci

im a bit clueless, but any help would be appreciated

tried removing some entries but we've had to resort to simplifying so that we can relist it quickly

Comment: I see only ascii characters in that string.  On the other hand, it does not look like a fully formed JSON string.

Comment: Would you be able to re-write the suspect entry in a way that would not cause any issues?

Comment: "breaks the whole system" -- need more details.  Crash?  Slow?  Error message?  "Cannot connect"?  What?

Comment: @RickJames loading the database from ingame jsut constantly loads